# Extension Theorem for $W^{1,p}(U)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Suppose $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is bounded an has $C^1$ boundary. The extension theorem states that there exists a bounded linear operator 
$$E:W^{1,p}(U)\to W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)$$
such that $Eu$ has compact support and $Eu|_U=u$. Furthermore, $||Eu||_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^n)}\le C||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)}$.

My question is, do we have $||Eu||_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}\le C||u||_{L^p(U)}$ and $||D(Eu)||_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}\le C||Du||_{L^p(U)}$?

I doubt so, but I do not see where it fails from the proof that Evans gives in his PDE book.

Comment: Surely, this depends on the precise construction of $E$. If I remember correctly, Evans uses some kind of reflection at $\partial U$. With this choice, your first inequality could be true. However, your second inequality fails for, e.g., constant functions $u = 1$ on $U$